# Does wxPython's text widget support custom text decorators?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm looking for a cross-platform rich text widget that supports non-trivial markup including the following, and I wonder if wxPython's text widget can be extended to do them:

- set text background color
- draw lines over and under text
- draw borders around text
- decorate content by overlaying lines and shapes (e.g., filled circles)
- indicate items in a gutter

To give you an idea, look at the middle pane here:

[image]

I found [wxRichTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_richtextctrl.html), but I can't tell whether these kinds of decorators are supported of not.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the wxPython demo package to see what all it supports. However I can tell you right now that it does not do everything you want. You can probably do what you want by creating a custom widget or just by drawing everything yourself though.

If these are hard requirements, I would recommend checking out another Python GUI toolkit